# test if a value is in a vector

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

I have a class Board, with an `operator==`, and a class `Graph`, containing a `Board*` (let's call it tab) and a `vector<Graph*>` (children).

I have 2 `vector<Graph*>`, named opened and closed.

How can i look every children in an element of opened, and add a child to opened if this child is not already in closed?

Here is my attempt, but it doesn't compile.

```
for (vector<Graph*>::iterator itr = opened[0]->getchildren().begin(); itr != opened[0]->getchildren().end(); ++itr) {

     // this doesn't compile
    vector<Graph*>::iterator it = find(closed.begin(), closed.end(), *itr);

    if(it != closed.end())
    {
        opened.push_back(*it);
    }
}
```

I get:

> no matching function for call to `'find(std::vector<Graph*>::iterator, std::vector<Graph*>::iterator, Graph*&)'`

I don't really understand how `std::find` works. But I'm open to every method.

Comment: Please paste the compiler error message

Comment: The compiler says  : no matching function for call to 'find(std::vector<Graph*>::iterator, std::vector<Graph*>::iterator, Board*)'|

Comment: Well, you're searching for a `Board*` in a vector of `Graph*`.

Comment: Of course it doesn't. Stop using pointers everywhere.

Answer (score 4):

[`std::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) returns an *iterator*, not a pointer to an iterator:

```
vector<Graph*>::iterator* it = NULL;
                        ↑
// that line doesn't compile
it = find(closed.begin(), closed.end(), (*itr)->tab);
```

Your `it` is a pointer. You just want the actual iterator type:

```
vector<Graph*>::iterator it = find(...);
```

You check validity not by comparing against `NULL` but rather by comparing against the end iterator that you pass in:

```
if (it != closed.end())
{
    ...
}
```

Given the error you just provided, the issue is that `find()` is looking for a specific value by using `operator==`. You are looking for a `Board*` in a vector of `Graph*`. Those two are not comparable - you can only look for a `Graph*`. Unless you are looking for a `Graph*` that *contains* a `Board*`, in which case you would want to provide your own predicate via `std::find_if`

Comment: Ah. Hum, it created an operator== for Graph, and used the line vector<Graph*>::iterator it = find(closed.begin(), closed.end(), itr); but the error is "no matching function call for 'find(std::vector<Graph*>::iterator, std::vector<Graph*>::iterator, std::vector<Graph*>::iterator&)'|". What is wrong in the value i try to compare ? :o

Comment: @Csi Now you're looking for an `iterator` in your vector of `Graph*`. That doesn't even make sense. The only thing that makes sense to look for in a `vector<Graph*>` is a `Graph*`. Also you should be getting a different error - you need to qualify your call as `std::find(...)`.

Comment: You mean i'm using `find(...)` instead of `std::find(...)` ? I have a using namespace std; If i use `*itr` , it will give me the `Graph*` of my vector, at the current index, right ? But i give me an error too. I edited the original post with the current code and error. It tells me that `*itr` is a type `Graph*&`

Answer (score 1):

Concerning `find`, you have to check against the `end` iterator

```
it = find(closed.begin(), closed.end(), (*itr)->tab);

if (it != closed.end())
{
   ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Other than the obvious error of comparing it against NULL instead of closed.end(), it seems that you want to look for a node of type Graph*.

std::find(start, finish, key) uses the iterators from first to last and invokes operator== on each element against 'key'. The 'things' stored in the vector and key have to be of the same type. Compiler is reporting they are not.

Key is of type Board*, while vector elements are Graph*.

Comment: _"Hope you have `using namespace std` specified already in your file."_ - Worst advice so far today.

Comment: Point taken! With the compiler error message it is clear that vector is indeed std::vector. One can't make assumptions. Besides, in a .cpp file we do rely on using directives. Some areas of code that I work on have such long qualifiers that we allow for using directives.  Feel free to edit the answer.

Comment: @KaylanS i created an operator== for class Graph and used the line vector<Graph*>::iterator it = find(closed.begin(), closed.end(), itr); but it's still wrong. Do you have an idea why ?

Comment: @KaylanS I edited the original post, can you have a look please ? I'm sure i'm pretty close to the solution but i miss something or there is something i didn't fully understood.

Answer (score 0):

I gave up on std::find and did two loops to compare opened and closed. Thanks for the help.